# How to change Visual Studio 2012 Quick Info Font and Color?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fonts, colors, text-editor, quickinfo

I use Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) "light with dark editor" theme and I have a problem with the quick info color. I want to change the colors because I cannot see it with the current settings.
Which property is for that under Tools->Environment->Fonts and Colors->... ?

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors, select "Editor tooltips" and then change the Plain text foreground color.